# Loop grabbing data its not supposed to and using it

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I've been working on this code that will check a google sheet for a date two weeks from now and send a reminder. The first time I run the code, it works great. The problem is, the second time I run the code it ignores the duplicate checker and then sends an email using data from a row that has already been sent. I'm trying to figure out A) why is it doing that, and B) how do I fix it.

```
function sendEmails3() {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 14); // Today's date, without time
    today = today.toLocaleDateString();
    var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B999
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
        var firstName = row[1]; // Second column
        var lastName = row[2]; // Third column
        var event1 = row[4];
        var event2 = row[6];
        var event3 = row[8];
        var emailSent = row[9];
        var sheetDate1 = row[13].toLocaleDateString();
        var sheetDate2 = row[14].toLocaleDateString();
        var sheetDate3 = row[15].toLocaleDateString();
        Logger.log(sheetDate1)
        if (sheetDate1 == today) {
            var event = event1;
            var sheetDate = sheetDate1;

        } else if (sheetDate2 == today) {
            var event = event2;
            var sheetDate = sheetDate2;
        } else if (sheetDate3 == today) {
            var sheetDate = sheetDate3;
            var event = event3;
        }

        if (sheetDate != today) {
            continue;
        }

        Logger.log(sheetDate)
        Logger.log(event)
        Logger.log(emailAddress)

        if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") { // Prevents sending duplicates
            var subject = "Reminding you that your " + event + " is coming up on " +
                sheetDate + "!";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {
                htmlBody: slsdf
            });
            sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
            // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            var sheetDate = "";
            Logger.log(sheetDate)
            var event = "";
        }
    }
}
```

please ignore the garbage in the part where its supposed to be emailing html, it's juts a huge pile of html and shouldn't effect anything.

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: what part of the code is formatted improperly?

Comment: The code is extremely unreadable since it is not indented properly and you are using braces irregularly.

Comment: is that any better?

Comment: Your code has some inconsistencies with `row` and `column` references. `_// Fetch the range of cells A2:B999
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999)._`  This is going to start at Row 2, Col 1, and get data for all rows with data and 999 columns, not to 999 rows of Column B.  **`sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, NumRows, NumCols)`**.  Then you have:  `_var emailAddress = **row** [0]; // First **column**_`.  Which is it?

Comment: @RonKloberdanz the first index of an array that is an element of a 2D array is indeed the first column. `var row = range.getValues()[0]; var row1col1 = row[0]; var row1col2 = row[1];`

Comment: @csrimpression you currently define a would-be constant `EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";` use it in your `setValue` call, but do not use it in your if-test. This isn't the source of your issue, but it could be the source of a future one.

Comment: @tehhowch - good point.  I just confused myself while looking through the code, trying to picture the operation in my head.

Comment: @csrimpression when you debug this code in the Script Editor, do you notice anything peculiar? You can set a breakpoint on the `var subject = ...` line so that it will pause whenever the if-test condition was true. You can then inspect all the script variables.

Comment: @tehhowch when I debug it for the second run through the variables for sheetDate and event have the data from the first row. I'm guessing it's because as its checking the dates it sets those variables and they don't get cleared or overwritten the second time I run it because then the dates don't match and then the variables don't change. Putting var event = ""; and var sheetDate = ""; before the if statements seems to have solved it. Thanks for helping me think it through!